# dissolve polygon JSTS

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to use JSTS to dissolve polygon's that I have on my map. It will dissolve `polygon1` & `polygon2` into one polygon in `DoEverything()` but if I change `polygon1` & `polygon2` to `polygon4` & `polygon5` then it will display the indiviual polygons but doesn't dissolve them into one.

What am I missing, what do I need to change in order to get this to work?

```
function DoEverything() {
var wkt = UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT(polygon1, polygon2);
```

to:

```
function DoEverything() {
var wkt = UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT(polygon4, polygon5);
```

and change

```
polygon1.setMap(null); 
polygon2.setMap(null);
```

to:

```
polygon4.setMap(null); 
polygon5.setMap(null);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/quqz096d/11/ - using polygon1 & polygon2 as arguments,

https://jsfiddle.net/quqz096d/12/ - using polygon4 & polygon5 as arguments

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT(poly1, poly2) {
    var wicket = new Wkt.Wkt();

    wicket.fromObject(poly1);
    var wkt1 = wicket.write();

    wicket.fromObject(poly2);
    var wkt2 = wicket.write();

    return [wkt1, wkt2];
  }

  function UseJstsToTestForIntersection(wkt1, wkt2) {
    // Instantiate JSTS WKTReader and get two JSTS geometry objects
    var wktReader = new jsts.io.WKTReader();
    var geom1 = wktReader.read(wkt1);
    var geom2 = wktReader.read(wkt2);

  }

  function UseJstsToDissolveGeometries(wkt1, wkt2) {
    // Instantiate JSTS WKTReader and get two JSTS geometry objects
    var wktReader = new jsts.io.WKTReader();
    var geom1 = wktReader.read(wkt1);
    var geom2 = wktReader.read(wkt2);

    // In JSTS, "union" is synonymous with "dissolve"
    var dissolvedGeometry = geom1.union(geom2);

    // Instantiate JSTS WKTWriter and get new geometry's WKT
    var wktWriter = new jsts.io.WKTWriter();
    var wkt = wktWriter.write(dissolvedGeometry);

    // Use Wicket to ingest the new geometry's WKT
    var wicket = new Wkt.Wkt();
    wicket.read(wkt);

    // Assemble your new polygon's options, I used object notation
    var polyOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#ff0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#ff0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    };

    // Let wicket return a Google Polygon with the options you set above
    var newPoly = wicket.toObject(polyOptions);

    polygon1.setMap(null);
    polygon2.setMap(null);

    newPoly.setMap(map);
  }


    var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.1951, 16.6068),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  var coords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.262985388398, 16.651552652553),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.268154293695, 16.696169517975),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.279279281222, 16.684044046655),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.29051372157, 16.69354790883),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.291693807108, 16.696711972181),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.291754288729, 16.700906003794),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.287224249824, 16.708018278815),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.269030413678, 16.716675506228),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.264399780154, 16.741519717396),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.257603048662, 16.755486775372),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.250805381075, 16.764647314794),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.224771273353 , 16.709762631879),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.211636932658 ,16.723347359512 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.190309978235, 16.733155536853),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.180168244216, 16.73897258718),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.169575489284,16.744102991998 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.162404281723, 16.749490888883 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.153547978232, 16.756852891603 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.133280070767 , 16.786993699245 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.107610095774 ,16.797050125784 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.09345145266, 16.767467010234 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.080895297287, 16.738570187728 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.080491255717 , 16.713371482742),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.072497012164,  16.703751047716),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.056097057925, 16.680771248057 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.046595816216,  16.642153144456 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.020460102381, 16.634173743535 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  49.028989499528, 16.606281622887),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.017651016771, 16.588388777446 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.035732241135,16.572490068959  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.06977908486,16.580280630492 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.091541070978,16.569729162022 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.093756140248,16.546612884063  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.094414014421, 16.509563030607),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.123726846521, 16.495515801661  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.141450293969,16.487353801526 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.182287496702 ,16.490864775023 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.231794094402,16.507802307393 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.251996444572 ,16.486292840573 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.262766673059,16.496309133774 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.262781359229,16.501518908421  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.256566333557, 16.531971044116),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.295657825466, 16.487131907305),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.326781008179, 16.532722798718),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.297128289052, 16.619936823457),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.288287925981, 16.646039397999),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.262985388398,16.651552652553 ),    
  ];

  var coords2 = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.2586746285,  16.548371315002),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.277604734014, 16.582703590393),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.296079782666, 16.619782447815),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.287123047871, 16.643128395081),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.261587425184,  16.650338172913),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.266964444325 , 16.700119972229),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.254193067134 ,16.712307929993 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.241642530476 ,16.737198829651 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.229313005054,16.715569496155 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.225052999213, 16.707673072815),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.212046498864, 16.72209262848),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.204083934969 ,16.758828163147 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.173455370467 , 16.769127845764 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.174016503645, 16.788182258606),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.165486592872, 16.801915168762),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  49.133261701694,16.784234046935 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.109332116515,  16.794962882995),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  49.108320753033, 16.742520332337),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.095957977994 ,16.722350120545 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  49.092136133539 ,16.67814731598 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(   49.083142397663,16.620812416077  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.079375786844 , 16.610770225524 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.082805100877 ,16.58630847931 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.119556967033  ,16.554894447327 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.131689219618 ,16.529488563538  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  49.149208344183 ,16.470437049866 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.159312714511 , 16.387009620667 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.168068168316 , 16.34855747223  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  49.193399748804, 16.343171596528),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  49.212214708212 ,16.3707447052 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.23671108962 ,  16.38288974762 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.245676979472 , 16.402201652527),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.252176231763 ,16.42288684845 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.250831629069 ,16.487946510315  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.262035532491,16.49721622467 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.253520797832,16.531205177308 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.2586746285, 16.548371315002  ),
  ];

  var coords3 = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.053694570768,   15.73890209198),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.060300338732,   15.741423368454),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.06277640633,   15.740881562233),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.068063880789,    15.738636553288),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.090232729029,   15.760430842639),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.085633529415, 15.783684253693),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.078631917353, 15.809079408646 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.071866851888,15.809352993966  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.055678463163,15.810270309448  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.058282197455,15.819840431214 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.051204256403, 15.828820466996 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.043904789772, 15.830676555634),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.030460394663,  15.833745002747),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.026742020752, 15.845045149327),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.020967459894, 15.84202632308),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.019493982719, 15.834200978279 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.011503675166, 15.820237398148 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 49.99085647193,15.817844867707  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.983544381282, 15.79580783844  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.99560183777, 15.783920288086),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.995146634027, 15.749373435974 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.005891051388, 15.748558044434),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.017363823547,15.711307525634 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.028682227671, 15.705685615539),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.03916419239,  15.686995983123),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.050525683613,  15.728216171264),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.053694570768, 15.73890209198),  
  ]

  var coords4 = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.086776271667 ,14.411187171937  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.08718930433, 14.411873817443),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.087740009013 , 14.41174507141),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.082907359565, 14.410758018493),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.086996556196, 14.411101341247),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.086321931625 ,  14.410479068754),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  50.085661065693,  14.410393238067 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.085812514942,14.409835338594  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.086473378783 ,14.409985542299 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.087244375084 , 14.410886764525),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.0882631726,14.412024021149 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.087505960295 ,14.412324428558 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.084752360161 ,14.409899711609 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  50.083609569657, 14.411412477494 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.088751912372, 14.411852359771),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.089247530711, 14.411637783049),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.089226880049,14.410382509231 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.089853279497, 14.409288167953),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.091085403974, 14.408987760543),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.09210411984 , 14.408161640166),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  50.091993989437, 14.405801296235),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.093446313761,14.405543804168 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.093611504263,14.407582283019 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.094850414859 , 14.409234523773 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.095889698486,14.413842558859 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.095542126007,14.419665634631 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.096033157431, 14.422328229993),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.097642524429, 14.433840732089),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.099334422681,14.442477906123 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.099443407119, 14.448153921403),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.100818675865, 14.449795894324),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.101612452327, 14.454089272766),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.103782528317, 14.455979391932),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.103819516174,14.469848424196 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.098112726191,14.465957880019 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.095710750594, 14.458061456681),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  50.091932040978, 14.438931941987),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.086266859813,14.438084363938 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.081557985814 , 14.433567523955),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.079774826525, 14.430488348007),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  50.077647341221,14.419426918031 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.073557347011, 14.415392875672),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.067208213772, 14.416809082031),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.066223403061, 14.420553445817 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.062759187941 ,14.421186447145 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.061677860817, 14.416154623032),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.047701064336 , 14.410994052886),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.051441926838, 14.406348466873),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.062869385515, 14.40908432007 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.081378984402, 14.406681060789),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.081764525075,  14.408440589906),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.081819602062, 14.408912658691),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.081874678984 , 14.410028457641),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.08237036844, 14.41123008728 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.086776271667 ,14.411187171937  ),
  ]


    var coords5 = [
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.06306406683, 14.4095993042),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.063284460323,14.412860870362 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.06802267553, 14.409084320069),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  50.070887415799, 14.409599304198),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.075845215724 ,14.41062927246 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  50.0836664799, 14.410114288329 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.091183605008,  14.413719177246),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.097708504849,14.418439865111 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.10293879554,  14.418439865111),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.10668223191, 14.417581558228),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  50.111030856788,  14.420757293702),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.110865726348,14.417066574096  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  50.111195986659, 14.408655166626 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.11174641545, 14.401874542236),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  50.112792212729, 14.397239685059),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.11438838559 ,14.393978118897 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.121212800443 , 14.393463134765),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.116259692911 , 14.378528594971 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.112461963426 ,  14.368658065796),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.112847254059, 14.353637695313),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.115158932757 , 14.331150054932),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.116259692911 ,14.318962097169 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.111085900142 ,14.304885864259 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  50.104590347649, 14.290294647218),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.09319347897,  14.295186996461),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  50.081243126025, 14.292011260987 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.064000732187 , 14.276990890504),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.048515857306 , 14.273643493653 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.042452801429 ,14.271926879883 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.045374187593 , 14.308319091797),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.040688859551, 14.318962097168),
    new google.maps.LatLng(  50.040302988625, 14.33183670044),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.045732458563,14.341707229615 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.046862372565 , 14.34986114502  ),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.042066944681 , 14.35715675354),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.058876398045, 14.390029907227),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.063064066831, 14.40788269043 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 50.06306406683, 14.4095993042),
  ]
    //brno
  var polygon1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [coords],
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#00FF00',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

    //brno
  var polygon2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [coords2],
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#0000FF',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  // pardubice
  var polygon3 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [coords3],
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#0000FF',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  var polygon4 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [coords4],
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#0000FF',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  var polygon5 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [coords5],
    strokeColor: '#ff00ff',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#ff00ff',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  polygon1.setMap(map);
  polygon2.setMap(map);
  polygon3.setMap(map);
  polygon4.setMap(map);
  polygon5.setMap(map);

  function DoEverything() {
    var wkt = UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT(polygon1, polygon2);
    UseJstsToTestForIntersection(wkt[0], wkt[1]);
    UseJstsToDissolveGeometries(wkt[0], wkt[1]);
  }

  DoEverything()

});
```